# Highcharts export server setup Https server

Tags: http, pdf, highcharts, server, export

I am trying to setup my highchart export server as http server, so that I can send request from code and get the desired highchart output as png, jpg, svg or pdf.

I followed the instructions from the link but could not get the job done.

https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server

I've started the node server by command:
highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1 --host localhost --port 3003--logLevel 4

But when I send a request through postman application I got this error:

```
Thu Jun 07 2018 15:01:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) [error] socket error: { Error: Parse Error, bytesParsed: 0, code: 'HPE_INVALID_METHOD', Packet:<Buffer 16 03 01 02 00 01 00 01 fc 03 03 74 3d ad 38 d0 cb 27 88 ec 95 9b c7 4c 87 9a 09 ed 26 7e ad 74 5d 90 50 7c ba ec 7d 26 28 c1 b1 20 3d f3 80 05 92 54 .. > }
```

My Postman request is :
URL: https://localhost:3003
Content-Type:application/json
Body: `{
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": [
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "May",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sep",
            "Oct",
            "Nov",
            "Dec"
        ]
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "data": [1,3,2,4],
            "type": "line"
        },
        {
            "data": [5,3,4,2],
            "type":"line"
        }
    ]
}`

I seems like I am missing something in request. But same request is working fine with CURL tool, awaiting a solution.

Comment: You should put chart config in `options` prop so it should look like this: `{ "options": { "xAxis": ... } }`

Answer (score 0):

Putting chart config in "options" node works.
like..

{
        "type": "image/png",
        "options": {
            "xAxis": {.......

Thanks @morganfree for your comment.